# Can line-height Attribute Inherit Parent Div's Height Property Or Access Height Property Of The Div To Which It Belongs?

Tags: html, height, css, inheritance

I have a div with height 50px that contains a child div. The height of the child div is *inherited* from the parent by using the css attribute/value pair: *height: 100%*.

```
    <div style="height: 50px;">
        <div style="height: 100%;">Some Text</div>
    </div>
```

I want to verically align the text in the child div and to do so I add the *line-height* property to the child div.

```
    <div style="height: 50px;">
        <div style="height: 100%; line-height: 50px;">Some Text</div>
    </div>
```

Notice that for *line-height* I have to explicitly define the height as 50px.

The child div can *inherit* the *height* property from the parent (using *height: 100%*) but for *line-height* I must explicitly set the value?

If so, this is (IMO) kindof messy because let's say I have a div that is nested 10 levels deep and it *inherits* the *height* property all the way down. Then if I want to vertically align the text within this div I have to not only *hard-code* the value to equal the height of the upper-most parent div but I have *navigate* through my code to find the parent that explicitly defines the height.

*Note that I don't want to define line-height at the parent level and then use inherit at the child node to get the value.*

It would be nice if there were a way to set *line-height* equal to the height of the div that it resides in. Perhaps the syntax would look like the following (totally made up):

```
<div style="height: 100%; line-height: from-property('height');">Some Text</div>
```

Where *line-height* uses the *from-property* method to access the height property. (Yes, I know having a method such as *from-property* introduces the potential for a circular dependency so perhaps some other way would be better. I am simply using it to express what I would like to have.)

Thanks!

Jan

Comment: You could also go the opposite way round, and let the line-height of the child control the height of the parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use jQuery to work out the height of the `parent()` and then to add line-height dynamically based on that height?

It would look something like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.lineHeightDiv').each(function(){
        var div_height = $(this).parent('div').height();
        $(this).css('lineHeight', (div_height / 2) + "px");
    });

});
```

Answer (score 7):

`line-height` is designed to set spacing between lines, and use this to align something vertically is not a good option. Unless you are sure the content will always in one line.

Use this to make it vertical center, not perfect though.

```
div.parent {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: This is a potential pitfall, and isn't supported in IE7. Using line-height to horizontally center text is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: Right, that's why I say it's not perfect. But here is some hack to make it work in IE7. http://www.jakpsatweb.cz/css/css-vertical-center-solution.html